# Status Publish to Google Assistant when publishing from Dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a problem like in the following pictures.

[image]

[image]

I can't release the latest version. I've tried configuring it with Google Assistant, and still can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue this week. What helped in my case was disconnecting and reconnecting Google assistant in the intents.
If you go to your intent in dialog flow then under events there are google assistant "chips" I removed those and added them back. I saved the intents and went to integrations. I clicked the "continue with integration" button and then "Test" to test my app. After this I was able to create a new release.

I hope this helps you as well.